# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDeep')

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the `getDeep()` function in Angular. I have already used it elsewhere in my code but in this particular part of the code it causes a `TypeError`. I would really appreciate it if someone can shed a light on why this is not working.

```
import { ConfigStateBase } from './config-state-base';
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigStateService } from '@abp/ng.core';

export class RuleOutputState extends ConfigStateBase {
    public readonly id: string;
    public readonly value: string;
    public readonly label: string;
    public readonly imageUrl?: string;
    public readonly fullImageUrl?: string;
    public readonly position: number;

    private readonly config: ConfigStateService;

    constructor(injector: Injector, ruleOutputExport: any) {
        super(injector);

        this.id = ruleOutputExport.id;
        this.value = ruleOutputExport.value;
        this.label = this.translatorService.getLabel(ruleOutputExport.labels, this.value);
        this.imageUrl = this.translatorService.getLabel(ruleOutputExport.images);
        console.log(this.imageUrl);
        this.fullImageUrl = this.createFullImageUrl(this.imageUrl);
        console.log(this.fullImageUrl);
        this.position = ruleOutputExport.position;
    }

    protected createFullImageUrl(imageUrl?: string): string {
        if (!imageUrl) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return `${this.config.getDeep('environment.application.questionImagesUrl')}/${imageUrl}`;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following line inside the constructor resolved my problem:

`this.config = injector.get(ConfigStateService);`

Answer (score 3):

Your `config` object is `undefined`.

You should probably pass it in the constructor, in order to be injected !

```
constructor(private readonly config: ConfigStateService, injector: Injector, ruleOutputExport: any) { 
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me identify the problem but I can't change the constructor because I have other constraints. I came up with the solution below.

Comment: @DerinÖZER Yeah I understand, it worsk too !